# Get Service from remote machines in a domain

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

Trying to get list of all machines in a Domain with a certain service

tried via all posts in here, helped per one machine, but if i use a text file with multiple machines, it failes

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\script\computers.txt
$service = "*crystal*"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
$servicestatus = Get-Service -ComputerName $computer -Name $service

}

$Data = $servicestatus | Select-Object Name,Machinename | Format-Table -AutoSize

Write($Data) | Out-File c:\script\output.txt -Append
```

Expected list of machines with service in table, instead got error:
This operation might require other privileges

same script, but with a direct machine name, works like a charm.
Any clue what is wrong?

Comment: The user account running this script - is it an admin on the remote machines? A non-admin user can enumerate services from the service control manager locally by default, but not remotely - you need to either update the `scmanager` sddl on the target system or use another remoting protocol (WMI/CIM or WinRM)

Comment: The user running the script is Domain Admin and part of local admins on all remote targets

Comment: And what does `sc.exe sdshow scmanager` say on the target?

Comment: [1] **_exactly_** what is in the `computers.txt`  file? [2] **_exactly_** what is the error text? [3] what is the `Write($Data)` function? [4] you are _resetting_ `$servicestatus` every time thru your loop.

Comment: Hey guys. eventually got it to work. ill edit the post with the script used.

Comment: @PavelSimanovsky Please do not edit an answer into your question. You're free to post an answer of your own if you managed to resolve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name *crystal*}
```

Eventually you may store the result from invoke into a variable and work with it. 
The benefit of using Invoke-Command, insted of foreach is that Invoke works in parallel, while foreach is serial ...

Hope it helps!

Best regards,

Ivan